# matlab using evalin in parfor

Tags: matlab, parfor

I have an issue with using `evalin` within a function that is being called in the body of a `parfor-loop`. The function looks as follow:

```
function returnData = extractFun(input)

    % assign close price to function call
    x = evalin('base','data');

    % extract prices
    returnData = x(input);

end
```

And the script calling the function looks like this:

```
% data-array = n-by-1 double
data = [1:1000]';

% loop and extract data
parfor i = 1:10

    % n-by-1 cell array containing 1-by-x doubles
    % doubles in var1 contain valid indicies for the data-variable

    var1 = {[1:10]; [1:30]};

    % perform cell-function since, cell2mat will not work due to
    % inconsistent dimensions of the double arrays contained in the cells

    extractData = cellfun(@returnData,var1,'UniformOutput',false);

    % do something with extractData

end
```

When I run the script in a `parfor`-loop, matlab throws an error, that the index exceeds the matrix dimensions, which must mean that the variable `x` is empty (or not being evaluated correctly). The weird thing is, that when I run the loop as a normal `for`-loop, everything works fine. I know about the transparency-issues with `parfor`-loops, hence I put the `evalin` into a separate function.

I would also be open to alternative solutions to my problem, which is extracting data from One data variable into a n-by-1 cell array as `doubles` without the use of additional loops, as I am intending to run this loop with a very high number of iterations.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`evalin` and `parfor` don't mix. Even if you run `parfor` with a local pool, you want to think of the workers that run the loop iterations as completely separate processes. In other words, they have no visibility of your base workspace at all. `evalin` is not allowed in the loop body for a reason; hiding it in a function doesn't change the fact that there is no variable `data` in the local base workspace of the worker, which will make the statement fail.

It is not clear to me why you fear the loop so much in this context. First of all, it's no longer 2006, when loops were still pretty bad for you; there has been some work done optimizing Matlab. Second, your `cellfun` call with `evalin` is a fairly inefficient way to simply read indices, and `cellfun` doesn't do much more than hide a loop away. Third, you're planning to run `parfor` here, which means that you may not be able to handle the likely higher memory usage coming from a fully vectorized loop replacement.

Consequently, just replace the `cellfun`-call with

```
extractData = cell(size(var));
for iVar = 1:numel(var)
    extractData{iVar} = data(var{iVar});
end
```

Comment: Have opted to use this solution. You are right - the additional processing time of the additional loop is not as bad as I thought and barely quicker than the cellfun (most likely as you said, because it is in fact a kind of loop after all). Thanks for your help!